# How can i create this time-table with stable time format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can i get result "My Dream Table Result"

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [count] int
  , [Time] nvarchar(50))
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int

SET @DateNow='00:00'
SET @i=1;
WHILE(@i<1440)
    BEGIN
        SET @DateNow=DATEADD(minute, 1, @DateNow)
        INSERT INTO #temp ([count], [Time]) VALUES (0, @DateNow)
        SET @i=@i+1
    END
SELECT [count],CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), [Time], 104) AS [Time] FROM  #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Table Result:

```
Count  |                 Time
-----------------------------
    0  |  Jan  1 1900 12:01AM
    0  |  Jan  1 1900 12:02AM
    0  |  Jan  1 1900 12:03AM
    0  |  Jan  1 1900 12:04AM
```

But i don't like this table Time format is not ok. I need this table
My Dream Table Result:

```
Count   |   Time
    0   |  12:01
    0   |  12:02
    0   |  12:03
    0   |  12:04
    ...
    ...
    0   |  22:01
    0   |  22:02
    0   |  22:03
    0   |  22:04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DateNow is a DateTime so will have the Date Compoent as well

```
select right(left(convert(nvarchar, @DateNow, 121), 16), 5)
```

will give you just the time component for putting in yoru Nvarchar column

```
while(@i<1440)
begin
    set @DateNow=DATEADD(minute, 1, @DateNow)
    insert into #temp ([count], [Time]) values(0, right(left(convert(nvarchar, @DateNow, 121), 16), 5))
    set @i=@i+1
end
SELECT [count], [Time] from  #temp
drop table #temp
```

And for shits'n'giggles, here's how to do it without relying on a DateTime Object.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
   [count] int,
   [Time] nvarchar(50) 
)


DECLARE @hour int, @min int, @i int
SELECT @hour = 0, @min = 0, @i = 1

WHILE (@hour < 24)
BEGIN
    WHILE (@min < 60)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp ([count], [time]) 
        VALUES (@i, REPLACE(STR(@hour, 2, 0), ' ', 0) + ':' + REPLACE(STR(@min, 2, 0), ' ', 0))
        set @min = @min + 1
        set @i=@i+1
    END     
    set @min = 0
    set @hour = @hour + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Can you look please my another question. Yhis question is related to  this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839386/how-can-i-left-out-join-these-temp-default-data-and-another-table
i need your help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 includes the concept of a time data type.

Check this out:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
testtime time(7) NULL,
testdate date NULL,
testdatetime datetime NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert table_1
(testtime, testdate, testdatetime)
values (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), GETDATE())

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_2
(
testtime time(0) NULL,
testdate date NULL,
testdatetime datetime NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert table_2
(testtime, testdate, testdatetime)
values (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), GETDATE())

select * from Table_2
select * from Table_1
```